# High side reverse voltage and overvoltage protection circuit

Tags: mosfet, reverse-polarity, over-voltage-protection, p-channel

Can someone provide an explanation why I still have a 50Vp negative waveform after the rectifier (waveform on Vch2) and after the overvoltage (output voltage) we have the same positive cycle.

It's possible to see when the BJT is switching but I'm having difficulties to understand why the signal over +-120V is passing through the MOSFETs generating a +-50Vp waveform.

I used a 20mA resistive load to get that waveform.

[image: I was using a 20mA resistive load.]

[image: Test circuit used.]

Comment: Looks like a fishy ground noise . The only thing expected is the narrow pulse.  I added a rectifier and cap https://tinyurl.com/yb4u5bp8   Those 10k's will get pretty hot with 1/2 W

Comment: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvae57b/slvae57b.pdf?ts=1652268044804&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.dk%252F

Comment: Many thanks, Tony. I'll try to improve the power input to reduce incoming noises and how I'm measuring the signal. I'll post the results...

Comment: If you have CM noise, Use two grounded probes with Ch1-2